# some times ftp_connect() is not working in php, remaining times it is working perfectly

Tags: php, networking, server, ftp

I have created, PHP application with some ftp images.

while using ftp_connect() function is working perfectly all times, Except some times. It is showing some error like 'FTP COULD NOT CONNECT'

At that time my physical FTP is connecting correctly. We can open and move files correctly.

Also we have tested the Network too.. No issues found.

How can we solve this? Kindly advice me..

Comment: If it fails and then you test it manually and it works chances are pretty good it was a minor glitch and if you tried your code again it would work. I would suggest adding some logic to your code to try the connection a couple of times before giving up and deciding that the connection could not be made.

Comment: Smells of issues with the network topology, a missmatch of the port ranges configured for the old fashioned ftp protocol in the client, the server and the package firewall. That typically leans to _some_ of the connections failing, while others work, depending on what ports are dynamically chosen for each file transfer.

Comment: Yes, we have used the Port. But it is working fine while using manually tested. Past 3 days too much hectic for this to solve.